# Using quail input-method to insert a string

Tags: string, input-method, insert, quail

The standard way to define an abbreviation using quail is as follows:

```
(quail-define-rules
("a" ?s ))
```

Inserting "a" gives "s".

I am wondering if one can insert an arbitrary string using quail, I tried the following but do not work

```
(quail-define-rules
("a" ?s?o?m?t?h?i?n?g ))

(quail-define-rules
("a" "something" ))
```

I know there are other methods to achieve this (e.g., abbrev-mode) but I am interested if there is way to do it using quail.

**Update** If one uses `("a" "something" )`, typing `a` inserts `s` and ignores `omething`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `quail-define-rules` is overkill (note the `rules`, plural, in the function name) — an alternative is `quail-defrule` (one rule...)

Directly from my scratch buffer

```
(quail-defrule "á" ["something"])
["something"]
```

— note that it's not `(quail-defrule "á" "something")`, to do what you want the string must be an element of a vector (ref. `C-h f quail-defrule RET`) —
then I typed `á` and I got

```
something
```

I have to mention that my knowledge in these matters is solely due to
(is stolen from...)
[this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32971/9672) from [Stefan](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/1979/stefan).