# TeX input method is fine — except for underscore

Tags: input-method

Most(?) programming languages permit to use Unicode in comments, strings
and, partially, variable names. It is handy to be able to write comments
like

```
# DETERMINATION OF CONSTANTS OF INTEGRATION, substituting Λᵢ in M(L)=0
```

etc, and it's *very handy* (at least for me) to use TeX input method for that.

In the above example I had to type `…\Lambda_i…` and that's fine, but when I type regular program text, like `n_intervals` what I get is `nᵢntervals`...

It is perfectly possible for me to type `n^Q_intervals` and get `n_intervals`
(typing `n_<space><backspace>intervals` works too)
but I'd like to either

- reverse the behaviour, i.e., typing `\Lambda^Q_i` to have `Λᵢ` and
  `n_intervals` to get `n_intervals` or
- typing `n__intervals` (have you seen `_` and `_`?) to get `n_intervals`.

BTW I'm not restricting your answers to the alternatives above.

Comment: In retrospect, the first alternative should be impossible...

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text ?

Comment: @Ian No, it is not. My Q is about Emacs, I've browsed the Q&A you referenced and it's **strictly** about TeX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I use

```
(defvar sm-quail-activate-hook-done nil)
(defun sm-quail-activate-hook ()
  ;; (define-key (quail-translation-keymap) "_" 'self-insert-command)
  (unless (member (quail-name) sm-quail-activate-hook-done)
    (push (quail-name) sm-quail-activate-hook-done)
    (when (member (quail-name) '("TeX"))
      ;; Copy the "_..." bindings to "\_...".
      (setf (alist-get ?_ (cdr (alist-get ?\\ (quail-map))))
            (alist-get ?_ (quail-map)))
      ;; Remove the "_..." bindings.
      (setf (alist-get ?_ (quail-map)) nil)
      ;; (quail-defrule "\\hline" ["------------------------"])
      )))
(add-hook 'quail-activate-hook #'sm-quail-activate-hook)
```

Rather than move the _... bindings to \_... you can also just remove the _... bindings and rely on the X11 input method using a key combination such as `Multi_key _ 1`.

Comment: Could you please edit the paragraph "Rather than..."  to fix the disappeared backslash? I tried it myself but my edit were too short and I'd prefer not to introduce gratuitous edits into _your_ post just to make it long enough...

Comment: @gboffi: Indeed, thanks for spotting that; fixed.

Answer (score 2):

As you say for yourself, typing `n_<space><backspace>intervals` gives what you want with two extra key presses.

### Proposed solution

- Type `n_<C-g>intervals` to get underscores when you need them inside `TeX` input method
- Use `C-\` to quickly toggle the input method

I do this for scientific Python code. I generally keep the `TeX` input method off, but turn it on for writing longer comments and documentation where I need Unicode.

For more information, see `<C-h> f` then `set-input-method`.

### Advantages

- Does not interfere with any other parts of the `TeX` input method
- No configuration
- You can reuse your `C-g` reflex to "abort this" when you see that Emacs is about to substitute something you don't want.

### Disadvantages

- Not exactly what you asked for

Comment: _"Not exactly what you asked for"_ but good enough indeed, especially the `C-\\` thing, to enter and exit with one keystroke from TeX input method. Tx